# Calling different action on same button using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a Save button on certHolderAddressChange screen as below:

```
<p:commandButton id="cmdSave" value="#{label.Save}" action="save" update="certHolderAddressChange" />
```

In this screen there is one checkbox. The requirement is: when this checkbox is checked and the Save button is clicked, then one popup is opened. The popup contains 2 buttons: Yes and No. On click of the Yes button, it calls a different action. Here is the popup code:

```
<p:dialog header="#{label.primaryAdd}" widgetVar="dlg1" showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" appendToBody="true">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="#{label.msgPrimary}" />
        <p:spacer width="30" height="10" />
        <h:outputText />
        <p:spacer width="30" height="10" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    <div align="center">
        <p:commandButton immediate="true" value="#{label.yes}" action="makeAdd"/>
        <p:spacer width="10" height="5" />
        <p:commandButton value="#{label.no}" onclick="dlg1.hide()" type="button"/>
    </div>
</p:dialog>
```

If checkbox is unchecked and Save button is clicked, a simple `"save"` action is called (no popup is open). To achieve this, I am using jQuery and on the basis of the checkbox I am firing the action. Here is the jQuery code:

```
<div>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{certHolderDetail.primaryInd}" id="primaryID" />
</div>
<script>
    jQuery("#cmdSave").click(function(e) {
        var textvalue = jQuery('#primaryID').val();
        if (textvalue == 'true') {
            dlg1.show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#save").click();
        }
    });                 
</script>
```

It's working but the problem is that on each condition the `"save"` action is called. But is I remove the `action="save"` from button, then the else part doesn't work. Only the if condition works in jQuery code.

I want to call `"save"` and `"makeAdd"` action on basis of the condition. How can I achieve this?

Also in each condition(checkbox checked or unchecked) "save" action is fired each time. i want to stop the save action when checkbox is checked.....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of jQuery you are using

1.6+ this is what you want

```
jQuery("#cmdSave").click(function(e) {
        var textvalue = jQuery('#primaryID').prop('checked');
        if (textvalue == true) {
            dlg1.show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#save").click();
        }
    });
```

<1.6+ this will work

```
jQuery("#cmdSave").click(function(e) {
        var textvalue = jQuery('#primaryID').attr('checked');
        if (textvalue == 'checked') {
            dlg1.show();
        } else {
            jQuery("#save").click();
        }
    });
```